# How to convert ISO duration and humanize it

Tags: duration, luxon, humanize

I have an ISO value of duration, that I need show like "XX years, XX months, XX days". I use for it **luxon** and **humanize-duration**. Duration.fromISO() works fine, but humanize-duration converting went wrong.
Could you help please?

```
transform(value: string): string {
    console.log(value);
    let formattedIso = Duration.fromISO(value);
    console.log(humanizeDuration(formattedIso, { language: 'en', units: ["y", "mo", "d"], round: true}));
}
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> P1Y11M3D; 1 year, 10 months, 28 days
>
> P2Y1M30D; 2 years, 1 month, 29 days

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/229